# cheerio jquery node js: obtaining href value

Tags: jquery, node.js, cheerio

[Source](http://prntscr.com/k7jswc)

Want `href` value so in this case: the link.

Want it for all values that follow same pattern of being in `.product-name` class.

Tried methods that return blank space/nothing.

Upon answering, please give a brief overview on some of the cheerio/jquery rules as I do not understand them.

FYI: `const $  = cheerio.load(response) //page source.`

Comment: Is anyone working on an answer  ?

Comment: And what have you tried to get the href of those elements?

Comment: console.log($('.product-name').attr('a[href]').text())

Comment: you won't get an answer faster if you write `BUMPPP`, it is in fact annoying and will have the opposite effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.product-name a[href]').each((index, elem)=>{
    console.log(index, $(elem).attr('href'));
});
/** .product-name : choose class .product-name
 *  .product-name a : choose tag a is child of class product-name
 *  and a[href] : choose tag a has attribute href, if you don't need, you can remove it.
 **/
```

For first link:

```
let firstElem = $('.product-name a[href]').get()[0]
console.log($(firstElem).attr('href'));
```

Comment: How do I call the first link ?

Comment: You can add condition `index == 0` (or use method in my answer edited)

Comment: Oh okay thanks, can you explain why you added the attr [href] in to '.product-name a[href]' and then do it again for .attr('href'))

Comment: `.attr('href')` : get attribute `href` of element

Comment: yes okay, but why did you write it after class .product-name

Comment: `.product-name a`: choose tag `a` has parent class`product-name` (may be parent of parent). This is css selector